# How to trim &nbsp; after getting text from DOMNode

Tags: php, domdocument

I am looking for "howto" to trim `&nbsp ;` entity from textContent of DOMNode. After reading text from node, it is not `'&nbsp ;'`. I am trying hexa, asci... but still I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dechex(ord(html_entity_decode("&nbsp;")));
```

Yields `a0` (normal (breaking) space would be `20`).
So, in text where `&nbsp;` is decoded, you can trim with `trim($string,"\xa0");`

If you also want the other default trims in it:

```
trim($string," \n\r\t\0\x0b\xa0");
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying this, but still there was someting... (�)

Comment: Rinse & repeat with the `dechex(ord())` trick, or show us the exact source if you want us to do it ;) Opening the output in a decent hex-editor might also shed some light on it.

Comment: After trim($string,"\xa0") the dechex(ord()) result is 'c2'.

Comment: Searching, it is probably second part of &nbsp; in UTF-8 charset... :-P

Comment: Hm, that one is not whitespace, and most often found in utf-8 text not actually presented with an utf-8 character set declaration....  Can you show us a bit more of the input? The actual string, either before or after extracting it from the DOMNode if possible...

Comment: Hm, indeed, wikipedia says you are probably right with `"\xc2\x0a"`, and as far as I am aware, `trim` is NOT multi-byte safe, so you wouldn't want to use `trim` for it. a `preg_replace("/(^\xc2\a0|\xc2\xa0$)/",'',$string);` seems to be necessary then.

Comment: In UTF-8 (multibyte) character set &nbsp; is '\xc2\xa0'.
    explode("\xc2\xa0", $element->textContent);
Works fine. I did not test trim. Thank you for help.

Comment: `"\xc2"` works fine now, but other valid, non-whitespace, utf-8 characters may start with it. A problem might occur later. For instance: try `"&nbsp;¼&nbsp;"`....

Comment: You think
    "\xc2\xa0" can match any other character?

Comment: No, `trim` takes a char-**list**, and is not multibyte safe. using `trim($string,"\xc2\xa0");` will remove all occurances of both `\xc2\xa0`, but **also** `\xc2`  on it's own. Go ahead, test it with the `¼` I gave you (which is `\xc2\xbc`, and will be reduced to the nonsense `\xbc` if at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
$text = 'abc&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+$/', '', $text); // output: abc
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Did you try to do so on text from DOMNode? There is no '&nbsp;' but some character...

Comment: If the character is whitespace, just do `trim($text)`